# Keywords in question refer user to documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

The new documentation tool that Stack Overflow currently has in beta looks extremely powerful. But I feel like questions that could be answered by documentation will still be asked on the site, and that wastes time for both askers, answerers and reviewers.

My suggestion is thus: you know how when you type in the title or description of your question and it pulls up a list of similar questions based off of keywords? Can a feature be implemented that pulls up documentation that shares those keywords? For example, a common python question that is asked here involves rounding numbers, where python programmers forget to convert to float.

Questions that have keywords like "python" "rounding", etc. could direct the user to the documentation while the programmer is still asking his or her question, even requesting that they mark the documentation provided as 'helpful' or 'not helpful'.

Thoughts? Just an idea I had to make what I am sure will be a powerful tool even more powerful!

Comment: Personally I'd hold off on this until the quality of the documentation improves.  There are currently some tags where clicking a documentation link should probably prompt the user to search Q&A instead.